# Dynamic population of dropdownlists in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

OK, I have a questions table, called QuestionnaireTable.
This Table has the following attributes:

```
QuestionnaireID    QuestionID    ChoiceType  ListOfAnswers QuestionLabel
---------------    ----------    ----------  ------------- -------------
AAA1               Quest1        enum        ListA         Pick a shape
AAA1               Quest2        string                    What is your name
AAA1               Quest3        enum        ListB         Pick a colour
AAA2               Quest1        enum        ListA         Pick a shape
AAA2               Quest4        number                    What is your age
```

I have a second table called QuestionMultiSelectTable
This Table has the following attributes:

```
ListOfAnswersID Options
----------      ----------
ListA           Square
ListA           Triangle
ListA           Circle
ListA           Rectangle
ListB           Blue
ListB           Red
```

So I read the the QuestionnaireTable into the Viewbag (into ViewBag.QuestionsList), and can iterate through each item for the correct questionnaire (Questionnaire "AAA1" as an example).
However, if the choicetype is an "enum" then I need to populate a dropdownlist using the distinct List in the QuestionMultiSelectTable table that has the same ListOfAnswersID

```
@foreach (var QuestionItem in ViewBag.QuestionsList)
{
    if (QuestionItem.OptionsType == "enum")
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-md-3">
                @QuestionItem.QuestionLabel:
            <div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.DropDownList((string)QuestionItem.QuestionID, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),
                         "Select answer",
                         new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="control-label col-md-3">
                    @QuestionItem.QuestionLabel:
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.TextBox((string)QuestionItem.QuestionLabel, "0", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
```

Now I am struggling to know how I can populate this dropdown list with the correct list of answers from the QuestionMultiSelectTable Table.
The List of questionnaires, questions and possible answers is constantly being changed, added to and removed from.

So any suggestions on the best way to do it in MVC without having to create a complex master class for the page? (Be aware this is just a small part of what's going on in the page, hence not wanting to go mucking around creating custom classes unless there is no other way)

I would ideally just like a single action I can call when each dropdownlist has/is being built, with the "ListOfAnswersID", and that will then populate it.
But I'm struggling to find examples anywhere.

Comment: Put at least one language tag on your question.

Comment: So if the user chooses an enum, you want to populate that dropdownlist with that enum's distinct list?

Comment: Not when a user selects anything.  I just want the dropdownlists populated before the user does anything.

Comment: @BigMB Can you please tell me if my answer helped, or if there is anything else you need?

Answer (score 0):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kpin7x

Creating tables - I added an id

```
CREATE TABLE [AHCCCS\KXBlau].[QuestionMultiSelect](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ListOfAnswersID] [char](5) NOT NULL,
    [Options] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_QuestionMultiSelect] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [AHCCCS\KXBlau].[Questionnaire](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionnaireID] [char](4) NULL,
    [QuestionID] [char](6) NULL,
    [ChoiceType] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [ListOfAnswers] [char](5) NULL,
    [QuestionLabel] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Questionnaire] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

GO

Controller/View Model

```
public class BigMBViewModel
{
    public IList<SelectListItem> QuestionMultiSelectList { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Tut141(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < formCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            if (formCollection[i].Contains("List"))
            {
                results.Add(formCollection[i]);
            }
        }

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Tut141()
    {
        //I am using entity framework.  You can use plain ADO
        //read the the QuestionnaireTable into the Viewbag (into ViewBag.QuestionsList
        using (SMARTEntities2 entity = new SMARTEntities2())
        {
            ViewBag.QuestionsList = entity.Questionnaires.ToList();
        }

        BigMBViewModel bmbViewModel = new BigMBViewModel { QuestionMultiSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>() };

        using (SMARTEntities2 entity = new SMARTEntities2())
        {
            entity.QuestionMultiSelects.ToList().ForEach(r => bmbViewModel.QuestionMultiSelectList.Add(
                new SelectListItem { Text = r.Options, Value = r.ListOfAnswersID + "-" + r.Id.ToString() }));            }

        return View(bmbViewModel);
    }
```

View

```
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.BigMBViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut141</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var QuestionItem in ViewBag.QuestionsList)
        {
            //fixed the next line
            //if (QuestionItem.OptionsType == "enum")
            if (QuestionItem.ChoiceType == "enum")
            {
                ++index;
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="control-label col-md-3">
                        @QuestionItem.QuestionLabel:
                        @*fixed the next end div to be an end div instead of a begin div*@
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
@{
                        var listOfAnswers = QuestionItem.ListOfAnswers;
                        var q = Model.QuestionMultiSelectList.ToList().Where(r => r.Value.Contains(listOfAnswers));
                        var theList = new
                        SelectList(Model.QuestionMultiSelectList, "Value", "Text");
                        }
                        @Html.DropDownList("theList" + index, q,
                            new { @id = "getThisValue", @class = "form-control" })

                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="control-label col-md-3">
                        @QuestionItem.QuestionLabel:
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.TextBox((string)QuestionItem.QuestionLabel, "0", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }
</body>
</html>
```